# asp.net mvc timespan format

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, timespan

I use in my view the following code

```
reservation.HeureRepas.ToString(@"hh\:mm")
```

and so I get for example: 14:45

But I would like to get a "H" in place of the column  as 14H45

Comment: The same way you did the `:` escape it with \

Comment: Thanks I thought I've tried that but I did probably wrong. Anyway It's working. Too easy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 reservation.HeureRepas.ToString(@"hh\Hmm")
```

Comment: See my comment above. Thanks